# Change int to time oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have cloumn "time" with datatype int i want to make a query that will show

the time like time not as int.

For example:

1356 convert it to 13:56

Comment: There's no `time` datatype in Oracle, so what you want is the string that *looks like* a time.

Comment: It's a pity that Oracle doesn't have a separate `TIME` data type. For that reason some people store times as numbers, e.g. 8:30 becomes 8.5. You, however, are storing the *string representation* of a time as a number, which is prone to errors. You are able thus to store numbers like 890 that do not represent a valid time string. If you store the times thus, make sure you have appropriate check constraints preventing you from invalid data.

Comment: As to conversion, you have two options: 1. Convert to `DATE`, which is Oracle's inappropriate name for datatime and ignore the date part. 2. Convert to `VARCHAR2`.

Comment: There is no data type `int` in Oracle either, by the way, but `NUMBER(n,0)` is ultimately an integer, so your column is probably defined as `NUMBER(4,0)`.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner Oracle provides interval datatypes that can handle validation, but unfortunately they do not support format models, and Oracle recommends to do messy `extract` and concatenation

Answer (score 3):

Since Oracle does not have`time` datatype, you may only format your number to look like time. But you need to be sure that your number has appropriate values of hour an minute.

> ```
> with a as (
>   select 1357 as tm from dual
>   union all
>   select 6789 from dual
> )
> select
>   to_char(tm, 'FM00G00',
>   q'[NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS=' :']') as tm
> from a
> ```
>
> ```
> | TM    |
> | :---- |
> | 13:57 |
> | 67:89 |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=49a8ff212af18168d31573c50e849ebe)*

**UPD**:
Alternatively you may consider to store your time values as appropriate Oracle's datatype: [`interval day to second`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Data-Types.html#GUID-B03DD036-66F8-4BD3-AF26-6D4433EBEC1C). This allows you to:

- Keep time arithmetics (they can be summed up or added to dates).
- Keep time restrictions: minute part will always be between 0 and 60, hour part will always be between 0 and 23. Also you can specify a precision of days and seconds to have upper boundary for interval without error-prone substrings or divisions.

The only drawback is formatting: thes still [do not support format models](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Data-Types.html#GUID-9B4F00D0-821A-4342-95AA-30CA43DBA124) (as your current approach do), but offer correct time semantics.

This way your initial time may be represented as

> ```
> create table t (
>   tm interval day(0) to second(0) /*Only one day without fractional seconds*/
> )
> ```

> ```
> insert into t
> select interval '23:57' hour(0) to minute from dual
> union all
> select interval '10:12:13' hour to second from dual
> ```

> ```
> /*Substring here is safe, because there's no format model
> and we know seconds precision is zero.
> So last 8 symbols will be a pure time with hh24:mi:ss*/
> select substr(to_char(tm), -8, 5) as formatted
> from t
> ```
>
> ```
> | FORMATTED |
> | :-------- |
> | 23:57     |
> | 10:12     |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=b4cb56aab3b71e50b839480595d8730c)*

Answer (score 2):

As your datatype for time column is 'int', you have to first convert    it to character datatype.

After converting you can use substr function to split the string and then concatenate the split strings adding ':' in the middle.

I hope the below sample query would satisfy your use case.

```
select substr(to_char(1356, 'FM0000'),1,2) || ':' || substr(to_char(1356, 'FM0000'),3,2) from dual;
```

To learn more about Oracle Substr and Concatenate function you can follow [this](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions162.htm) and [this](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/operators003.htm#i997789) link respectively.

Comment: Make this `to_char(1356, 'FM0000')` in order to get four digits in your time strings.

Comment: Yes, making `to_char(1356, 'FM0000')` will add leading zeros if the number is less than 4 digts. Thanks @ThorstenKettner.

Answer (score 0):

You can do:-

TO_DATE((TO_CHAR(time), 6, '0'), 'HH24MISS')

Yet another method is to use an NLS trick for NUMBER formatting:

SELECT TO_CHAR(time, 'fm00G00G00',
'NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS=''.:''')

Comment: Thanks. i got for example from 1356 -- 00:13:56, if i dont want the 00 and only 13:56?

Answer (score 0):

Try casting integer column to date/time format.
You can use this in case of your issue:

select to_char(to_date(164741, 'hh24miss'),'hh:mi')